# Multiple jenkins/gerrit projects

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

We're finishing the setup of our new CI system, including git, gerrit and jenkins for automated testing and code reviews, and we're finding a strange situation:

We have three different gerrit projects, each one of them with its own Jenkins job. We used [this](http://unethicalblogger.com/2009/12/07/code-review-with-gerrit-a-mostly-visual-guide.html) guide as setup reference, and everything is installed and apparently working fine.

Our first project was setup, and tested with a sample change patch. Jenkins was triggered correctly, passed the test and voted "Verified" to the build as expected. So far so good!

But: When we tried to setup a second project, we find that a change patch in one of the projects triggers changed in every jenkins job. For example:

Let's say we have GerritProjectA, and GerritProjectB, each one with a JenkinsProjectA and JenkinsProjectB. When a change is submitted to GerritProjectA, both JenkinsProjectA and JenkinsProjectB are triggered. Also, something gets mixed up in the gerrit voting after the build: This is the info in sshd_log after one of the builds (one in JenkinsProjectB):

```
gerrit approve 10,3 --message '\''Build Failed 
    http://jenkins-server:8080/job/projectA/6/ : FAILURE

    http://jenkins-server:8080/job/projectB/59/ : Correcto'\!''\'' --
        verified -2 --code-review 0' 14ms 6ms 1
```

As you can see, the gerrit approve command is mixed up with information for two different jenkins jobs...

Sample setup for any jenkins job:

```
Repository URL: ssh://jenkins@gerrit-server:29418/projectA.git
Banches to build: $GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION
Build triggered by Gerrit event:
Project Type: Plain
Branches: Path **
```

Software versions:

```
Jenkins: 1.458
Gerrit plugin: 2.5.1
Gerrit: 2-3 rc0
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Domingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

One of the Jenkins jobs (let's call it JenkinsJobB), in the "Gerrit Trigger" part of the configuration didn't have the name of the git repository in the pattern.

If you have multiple jenkins jobs for gerrit projects, you need to setup the gerrit trigger like this (at least in my case):

```
Type: Plain
Pattern: (repository name)

Branches
Type: Path
Pattern: ** (or the branch name if you just want to watch one).
```